# Pygame window closes, but program still hangs on exit (Mac)

Tags: python, pygame

Whenever I close a Pygame window, the program stays open. [The window closes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo1RQ.png), but [the little Pygame icon stays in my dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVnC4.png), and only closes when I force quit Pygame or close the interactive shell that opens. I'm running it from IDLE because when I try to run programs from the command line, it just says I haven't downloaded Pygame, despite the fact that when I use `pip install pygame`, it says it's already installed. Is there some way to fix this hanging problem with IDLE or make it work with the command line? It doesn't really do anything, but it gets really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the program is still "running" , happens to me on a mac too, try updating PIP `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip` or if writing code in IDLE,`pygame.quit`. Hope that helps, Jontus

Comment: Thanks, but pip is on the latest version and I always have `pygame.quit` and `sys.exit` in my code.